# Filling Map with GregorianCalendar

Tags: dictionary, fill

I have a problem with filling a LinkedHashMap with GregorianCalendar-Objects.

I creat a GregorianCalendar starttime. Then I fill it into an ArrayList and add 200 Milliseconds 50 times. After that, I fill these values in a Map together with a double from another ArrayList. When I make a System out of the Map it only gives me the last value of the time list but all values from the double list.

```
starttime = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 1, 13, 0, 0);
starttime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
GregorianCalendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
time.setTimeInMillis(starttime.getTimeInMillis());

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    time.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 200);

    timeList.add(time.getTimeInMillis());

}

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    time.setTimeInMillis(timeList.get(i));

    inputMap.put(time, valueList.get(i));   

}

for (Entry<GregorianCalendar, Double> entry : inputMap.entrySet()) {

    System.out.println(entry.getKey().getTime().toString()+" " 

    +entry.getKey().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)+ " = " + entry.getValue());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The Problem is, that time is a reference in the inputMap. So you have to create a new GregorianCalendar in the filling loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    GregorianCalendar gregCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    gregCal.setTimeInMillis(starttime.getTimeInMillis());
    inputMap.put(gregCal, valueList.get(i));
    starttime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 200);
}
```